# Determine if Rows if returned

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, datatable, datarow

I have a function that returns a single data row from a data table based on a certain value in a certain column.  what if the value doesnt produce a row, how can i determine that by using the empty row?

ie, if i had a query that returned a table that had 0 rows, I could say

```
         if(table.rows.count == 0)  
          { 
            do stuff
          }
```

but i cannot do

```
        if(row.columns.count)
         {
           do stuff
         }
```

ive tried dbnull and row.haserrors but thats not what i am looking for.  i want to test the row because i need to use it if it does have values

I pass a datatable to the function.  then loop through to find a specific value on a specific field.  if i find it, i assign that row and return it.  otherwise it just returns a row

so I got Dim myRow as DataRow

Loop
if value found, MyRow = thisRow
Next

return myRow

(sorry it is vb)

Comment: But how are you *assigning* `row` here?

Comment: How are you getting the data? If you use a DataReader, determining whether there are any rows returned is pretty easy.

Comment: what is wrong with your first condition?  `if (table.Rows.Count == 0)` ?

Comment: You do realize that you're not comparing `columns.count` to anything, right?  Maybe an `== 0` or `> 0` would help.  Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: sorry, im just typing this rather than showing my code, i understand your concern about the column count, but that doesnt even exist

Comment: Instead of a for loop I would suggest `DataTable.Select` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx which "Gets an array of all DataRow objects that match the filter criteria".  This returns an array of DataRow[] objects which will have a Length property you can check

Answer (score 0):

Check if `DataRow` is `null`, if not then loop through the `ItemArray` and see if any of the columns have data, like this:

```
// Assume it is empty
bool isRowEmpty = true;

if (row != null)
{
    foreach(var columnValue in row.ItemArray)
    {
        if (columnValue != null)
        {
            isRowEmpty = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the VB.NET version:

```
' Assume it is empty
Dim isRowEmpty As Boolean = True

If row IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each columnValue As var In row.ItemArray
        If columnValue IsNot Nothing Then
            isRowEmpty = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: when i try to see if the row is null, intellisense dont like it.  only lets me compare it to nullable,even then it gives an error

Comment: Is `row` a `DataRow` or something else?

Comment: Using similar logic as @Karl Anderson, you could return a row index of the row that is found.  If a match is not found, return -1.

Comment: i cant return an int or a bool, i need to return a row.  but nonetheless,  im gonna see if IsDbNull(myRow) works, if not I will try the row.table.count.  howeever karl's vb version looks like it should work.  it is a datarow.  im not the best with vb,  this is nothing is odd

Comment: @user2070677 - it would help if you posted your actual code instead of the pseudo-code, including the function that returns the `DataRow` object.